# Reporting solutions on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, reporting, report

Actually, reporting has two separated tasks:

1. Query data from one or more Kind(s)
2. Rendering data into PDF, Excel, HTML format

For question #1:
AppEngine does not support JOIN. Thus what is best solution for this purpose?

For question #2:
Is there any solution which are able to run on AppEngine?

Thanks

Comment: Fyi, I think Google is planning to release support for a relational database in their upcoming business version.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have, for example, a customer and their orders, include the orders data in the same record as the customer instead of using a relational join to grab it. BigTable allows you to store arbitrary muti-value attributes in any column.
2. A simple solution (assuming you want to use JSP) is [DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org/).